# ASPX file pointed in AngularJS $route + ngView is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS $route + ngView to point to some ASPX file. 
Part of the code is like this :

```
$routeProvider('/action', {
                         templateUrl: 'pages/action.aspx',
                         controller: 'mainController'
                      });
```

When I go to "/action", it correctly loads the ASPX and show the result. The problem is: when I press a button inside the ASPX file, it routes to root directory and shows the "The resource cannot be found" error. In fact it changes the path of ASPX file. How can I resolve this issue? Is it possible to use ASPX file in AngularJS routing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it works.
you can wrap SPA application inside ASPX file but not the other way around.
ASPX file generates a full html file ,not just partial html block.
user controls makes more sense but I don't see how to can render user control outside of ASPX framework. 
Honestly I don't understand what are you trying to pull,
It makes no sense to load ASPX files inside angular framework.